# find and replace words in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a `4902x1` cell array which contains strings like Blue. or Green. I want to replace a number of these strings with another word. How can this be done in MATLAB?

For instance find

```
Blue.
Red. 
Green.
```

Replace with:

```
Colour.
```

Edit:

```
strArray = {'green.','black.'};
strMatch = strmatch(strArray, Book2);
strArray( strMatch(str,strArray)) = {'colour'};
```

Comment: strArray in your example is not a cell array so I think thats why it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a cell array of strings (in your example strArray is not a cell array) I would define a small function to do the logic and then use `cellfun`:

```
function y = changecolor(str)
if( strcmpi('green',str) || strcmpi('blue',str) )
    y = 'color';
else
    y = str;
end
```

Then you can get your new array with:

```
changed_array = cellfun(@changecolor, strCellArray,'Uniform',false)
```

Comment: hmmm `Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.`

Comment: Using this how can I add in another if else?

Comment: for instance its fine changing green, blue to colour but if I wanted to change black, white to shade... I cant see how to add another if else?

Comment: elseif( strcmpi('black',str) || strcmpi('white',str) )
    y = 'shade';

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
strArray( strmatch(str,strArray) ) = {'newString'};
```

In this example you need to set the variable str to the string you wish to search for, 
e.g. str ='green.'

**EDIT**: Updated to reflect your edits to original post.

```
strArray = {'green.','black.'};
strMatch = strmatch(strArray, Book2); % This line is unnecessary and if Book2 is not a string variable it will not work

strArray( strMatch(str,strArray)) = {'colour'}; % For this line to work you need declare a string value for the variable str, e.g. str='green.'
```

Comment: I attempted what you said but I get Index exceeds matrix
dimensions. I put an edit up showing what I tryed.

Comment: It will work if you have a cell array as you first indicated. Change your strArray to a cell array by using the {} rather than [].

Comment: Nah still doesnt work - `Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of
class 'cell'.`

Comment: I updated my response to answer your questions in the comments.

Comment: makes no sense and once again index exceeds matrix dimensions, why would I use strArray with green and black then declare str as only one color to match i.e green?

Comment: strArray is what I am suppose to look for...? Not str?

Comment: No, str is the string you're looking for inside a cell array of strings called strArray. In my solution you would have to repeat this for each color, so the solution from robince is more general.